# ID_Token and Access_Token in Google IDP

Tags: jwt, access-token, google-identity

I have an application which currently works with Azure AD Oauth 2.0. It accepts the JWT token from AAD as a access_token and signs the user in. I am trying to setup this with Google IDP and I am running into an issue. Google IDP returns the JWT token as id_token which the application doesn't recognize and value returned in access_token is not a valid JWT. Is there a way to receive the JWT as access_token in Google? How can I achieve this? the Application can only accept JWT as access_token it cant be changed, this an application from Oracle Corp.

Comment: Did you use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to exchange the identity token from Google for an access token from Microsoft Identity platform?

Comment: No, I am not exchanging Google's Identity token for MS Access Token.
The application is currently able to accept access token from Azure AD to sign-in.  I am trying to setup similar authentication for user accounts in Google IDP. This is a PoC for a customer who is has users in Google IDP, they don't have a Azure AD tenant so exchanging token with MS AAD is not an option.

Comment: After further investigation and due to the nature and specific requirement of your issue, it will be appropriate for you to directly contact [Workspace Developer Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110#support-pilot), they are specialists on this topic and I'm sure they can guide you.

To reach them out, you need to go to the [following link](https://support.google.com/a/contact/wsdev) and fill the form describing your issue.